# Why the difference in same browser? firefox selenium webdriver

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

So when I manually launch firefox, I see my firebug button on the upper right corner. when I launch firefox via webdriver, the button is not there. why? I don't have any profiles set up.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
```

Answer (score 4):

Each instance of an HtmlUnitDriver, ChromeDriver and FirefoxDriver is completely independent of every other instance (in the case of firefox and chrome, each instance has its own anonymous profile it uses).  Which means that your profile that has the firebug attached to it is not being used and hence the no firebug button.

Comment: More correctly, WebDriver starts each browser with a clean profile, not with your personal profile.  But the effect is just as CBRRAcer says.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this page which illustrates how to run it w/ firebug.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver